# show that χ(G)≤√(2|E|)

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I was given an Homework exercise where I need to show that χ(G)≤√(2|E|)

So far I've manged to prove that:

 1. χ(G)+χ(G′)≤n+1 

 2. χ(G)≤maximin{di,i}

Now I tried using (1) because I know that there's a link between n+1 and |E| but then I was left with G'...

 Can someone help solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For a clique $K_n$ you have 
$$n = \chi(K_n) \not\leq \sqrt{2\big|E(K_n)\big|} = \sqrt{n(n-1)},$$
in other words that inequality is not true. However, you can prove $$\chi(G)\big(\chi(G)-1\big) \leq 2\big|E(G)\big|.$$

**Hint:**

- Imagine there is no edge between some pair of different colors, what could you do?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$